# Google want to punish third party cookies, but all my 3rd party cookies are from Google

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, google-analytics, third-party-cookies

I run a website using google translate, and google analytics.
I saw recently that google will block some features to fight against websites using third party cookies, and I have 8 alerts on my website telling there is some, but all of them are from google's services

[image]

[image]

So I don't understand, how I am supposed to remove "third party cookies" if google inject them themself? I don't understand at all and I don't find any documentation about that. I could just remove google services and I have 0 third party cookies, but I want to keep using analytics and translate

Thanks for help

Comment: Thomas have you found a solution? I've got the same issue with analytics and google ads

Comment: No ... @maniek099

Answer (score 1):

Good job paying attention to that issue/warning at all and inspecting your third party cookies.

Some have it a bit differently too:

[image: 3p cookie deprecation warnings]

Yes, it's a known fact that Google uses them profusely and Google might be a bit too eager to follow safari's stunt.

In general, what you should do is warn your marketing about the cookies that are going to be deprecated so that they would start thinking on how that would impact them and what they can do to prepare for that. Although at this point they should know about it more than you.

Revisit all your google fonts, translate and whatnot after the cookie is deprecated. It shouldn't be necessary for them to function properly. It's mostly used for google's internal analytics.